# how to get required output from json stringify array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My array look like this after use this code -:

```
var array=xmlhttrequest.responseText;

console.log(array);

["{\"result\":{\"isvalid\":true,\"address\":\"3EL5SKSjEzFQDBmXA5JFbsZu48vKnNSdDH\",\"scriptPubKey\":\"a9148aa3d53255b44655f82d163f37ecb68057f2edf487\",\"ismine\":false,\"iswatchonly\":false,\"isscript\":true},\"error\":null,\"id\":\"curltest\"}\n"]
```

I want value of isvalid , how can i get this .

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange response. It's a stringified array, and that array contains a single item, which is *another* stringified object. Here's one option:

```js
const responseText = String.raw`["{\"result\":{\"isvalid\":true,\"address\":\"3EL5SKSjEzFQDBmXA5JFbsZu48vKnNSdDH\",\"scriptPubKey\":\"a9148aa3d53255b44655f82d163f37ecb68057f2edf487\",\"ismine\":false,\"iswatchonly\":false,\"isscript\":true},\"error\":null,\"id\":\"curltest\"}\n"]`;
const [ stringItem ] = JSON.parse(responseText);
const itemObj = JSON.parse(stringItem);
const isvalid = itemObj.result.isvalid;
console.log(isvalid);
```

Note: While testing like this, you have to use `String.raw` so that the single backslashes are interpreted as literal backslashes and not unnecessary escape characters

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is an array as you can see it is wrapped inside [ ]. The inner content is a string, so you need to `JSON.parse` to convert into an object. Here is how you will get it `JSON.parse(myData[0]).result.isvalid`

[image]

```js
var myData = ["{\"result\":{\"isvalid\":true,\"address\":\"3EL5SKSjEzFQDBmXA5JFbsZu48vKnNSdDH\",\"scriptPubKey\":\"a9148aa3d53255b44655f82d163f37ecb68057f2edf487\",\"ismine\":false,\"iswatchonly\":false,\"isscript\":true},\"error\":null,\"id\":\"curltest\"}\n"];

console.log("Is Valid: "+JSON.parse(myData[0]).result.isvalid);
```

Comment: The `responseText` is certainly a *string*, not an array. Also, `var myData = ["{\"result\" ...` won't accurately reflect what OP has, which is *literal* backslashes. (in your code, they're being interpreted as unnecessary escape characters)

Answer (score 0):

use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(array);
```

but I would try and eliminate all the unnecessary chars before using [string.replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
var json = array.replace("\", "");
```